# Find number with given property

Tags: number-theory

How can we find the smallest $3$-digit number $n$ such that $2 \mid n$, $3 \mid n+1$, $4 \mid n+2$, $5 \mid n+3$ and $6 \mid n+4$ ?

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: If $$2|n$$ then $n$ must be even, then $n$ can be written in the form $$n=2m$$

Comment: I see. And from all the other relations, $3 \mid n+1$, $4 \mid n+2$, $5 \mid n+3$ and $6 \mid n+4$, we get that $m \geq 1$ and the smallest value for $m$ is $1$ and so the smallest value for $n$ is $2$. Right? @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: @Evinda If 5 | (n+3), then n must end in a 2 or a 7. Since n is even, it must end in a 2. If 3 | (n+1), then the three digits of n must add up to a number that is congruent to 2 (mod 3).

Comment: Why does $n$ have to end in a 2 or a 7? @JoelPereira

Comment: The answer is $122$... just so you can check your method.

Comment: @Evinda Multiples of 5 have a ones digit of 5 or 0. So the one's digit of n+3 is either 5 or 0. So if we subtract 3 from n+3, that means the ones digit for n is 2 or 7

Comment: Check Chinese Remainder Theorem:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: @JoelPereira If the one's digit of n+3 is either 5 or 0, why isn't the one's digit for n either 2 or -3? How do we get 7? Also does it hold that any number that ends in 7 is odd?

Comment: @JoelPereira Also how do we get from the fact that  3 | (n+1), that then the three digits of n must add up to a number that is congruent to 2 (mod 3) ?

Comment: @Evinda It is known that if n is a multiple of 3, the sum of the digits of n is also a multilple of 3. So if n+1 is a multiple of 3 and we subtract 1, the sum of the digits of n is 1 less. Thus the sum has a remainder of 2 when divided by n, ie 2 (mod 3)

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot :) @JoelPereira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JoelPereira showed, the last digit must be $2$.  Moreover, the three digits must add up to a number that is congruent to $2~(\mod 3)$.  So we start at the beginning of three digit numbers, i.e., of the form $1x2$ where $x$ is an unknown digit.  We search for the first digit $x$ for which $1 + x + 2 \equiv 2~(\mod 3)$ and find $x=2$ works for all the cases.

Thus the answer is $122$.

Comment: First of all, I haven't still understood why the three digits must add up to a number that is congruent to $2 \pmod{3}$ ? Why is the number that corresponds to the highest term equal to $1$ ?

Comment: @Evinda:  The smallest three-digit numbers begin with a $1$, of course.

Comment: Ah yes.  Could you explain to me how we get that the three digits of $n$ must add up to a number that is congruent to 2 (mod3) ? @DavidG.Stork

Comment: @Evinda Be sure to also learn the general methods like CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem since special tricks like the above won't always be so efficient in general, esp. for larger numbers. If this problem is an exercise in a book around CRT then it may well have been designed to give you experience applying it.

Answer (score 1):

$\bmod 6\!:\ n\equiv -4\equiv 2$
$\bmod 5\!:\ n\equiv -3\equiv 2$
$\bmod 4\!:\ n\equiv -2\equiv 2$
$\bmod 3\!:\ n\equiv -1\equiv 2$
$\bmod 2\!:\ n\equiv\ \ \ 0\equiv 2$

So the congruences are equivalent to $\,2,3,4,5,6\mid n-2\iff {\rm lcm}(2,3,4,5,6)\mid n-2$

But  $\,{\rm lcm}(2,3,4,5,6) =  {\rm lcm}(4,5,6) = {\rm lcm}(12,5) = 60,\,$ so $\,n= 2+60k$

Comment: Not three digits.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It is a hint.... What remains is trivial.

Comment: OK... fair enough.  (+1) . Judging from the poster's apparent understanding, more detail would have helped.